# How to enable bluetooth in Windows 10 phone emulator?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-runtime, emulation

Bluetooth is on and working on the pc, but can't be enabled from the Windows Phone emulator settings. Any hints ?

Answer (score -1):

"Bluetooth cannot be tested using Windows Phone Emulator"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/apps/jj207007(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: "Test Bluetooth using a Windows Phone 8 device"